# Why am I receiving an HTTP 500 error when trying to sync my VS Code code with GitHub using git push?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-push

**Configurations**

> - Mac OS: 13.3
> - VS code: Version: 1.78.2

**Error**

I can't sync my code on VS code with my code on Github

```bash
 2 files changed, 839 insertions(+), 124 deletions(-)
Enumerating objects: 105, done.
Counting objects: 100% (105/105), done.
Delta compression using up to 10 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (89/89), done.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (99/99), 7.57 GiB | 8.79 MiB/s, done.
Total 99 (delta 44), reused 3 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

I tried to push my code to GitHub using my script

here is the script:

```bash
x#!/bin/zsh

# Set the commit message
commit_message="Commit changes"

# Sync with the remote repository
git pull

# Add all files to the staging area
git add .

# Commit the changes with the specified commit message
git commit -m "$commit_message"

# Push the changes to the remote repository
git push
```

I was expecting my code to be updated on Github.

Comment: *Writing objects: 100% (99/99), **7.57 GiB*** You attempted to push something huge.

Comment: if there is a way to shard it, I am willing to do it, it is some code that has been pilling up since I was working local

Comment: HTTP 500 indicates a server-side problem - but in this case it's likely that an upstream server timed out while handling your huge request, and that the load balancer returned a 500 to close the session as cleanly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would first make sure my repository does not include in its history any large object:

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 5M
```

([install `git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md) first)

And double-check your `.gitignore`, which should have excluded any large file, like binaries or archives.

Then you can try again.